# Make scrolling text content between 2 fixed divs (top and bottom)

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/4n496n23/1/

Top block contains image, so we don't really know its height.

HTML

```
<div id="top-block">

</div>
<div id="text-block">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</div>
<div id="bottom-block">

</div>
```

Comment: how much you provide maximum height to top-block ??

Comment: top block height can to be up to 60%

Comment: Nope, it's different questions. If you change wrapper block (named section) height to 100% it brokes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4n496n23/9/

Most of the fixes are on this div:

```
#text-block {
  display:block;
  height:calc(100% - 4.5em);
  font-size: 2em;
  overflow-Y: scroll;
}
```

Also changed the `position` values of the other divs and created a fixed wrapper the size of the viewport. Good luck.

Comment: No problem. Consider upvoting the answer and also the answer referencing `flex` below this one.

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
#top-block {
  background-color: #569688
}
#text-block {
  font-size: 2em;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
#bottom-block {
  background-color: #b9e111
}
```

```html
<div id="top-block">
  The Extremes
  <br/>of Good
</div>
<div id="text-block">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</div>
<div id="bottom-block">
  Finibus Bonorum
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the fiddle what you want to achieve this only or not
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4n496n23/7/)

```
<div id="text-block">
 <span> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</span>
</div>

#text-block {
  font-size: 2em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:9em;
  margin-top:3em;
}
```